# Datastage Heap Size

Tags: datastage, heap-size

Can you please help me, because am stuck with a problem of heap size.

I am using a jdbc connector to connect to a PostgreSQL database. I have about 7 million data into my table. I had to set my heap size about 4096 Mb (4 GB) so that my job does not fail with the error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

So far I have not find a solution, to read data from this connector using Fetch Size just like Oracle Array Size. See below are the recommendations of IBM while using the fetch size.

1. Single Query
2. Auto Commit is disable
3. Right use of charset and length of fields.

All are set accordingly but we are unable to use the fetch size correctly. We have also tested it by using java language and the fetch size and it worked, so the problem may not be with the driver.

Can you guys share your experience with me? Anyone had similar problems, how did you solved it except increasing the heap size. In fact we don't want to increase the heap size more than this, we would like to make the connector read small packets of data using a moderate heap size instead of using a rather big size heap size.

Kind regards,
Knlix.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do the following:

1. Increase transaction size to 10,000 and reduce the array size. This would cause a smaller array to be created thus saving temp space.
2. Go for using APT_NOJOBMON env variable. This will not monitor the job and save space.
3. You can try to check proper partitioning techniques at required stages.
4. Try to break the job into multiple jobs and the job logic. For example: you have a SQL at source which is pulling 7 million data. Instead of pulling the same at one job break it down to multiple jobs,pull data chunk by chunk later integrate if necessary to do all at once or simply let the jobs run one after another so that the temp space gets cleared at the end of each job.
5. If possible request the admin to increase datastage spool space

Comment: Hello Sourabh, thanks for you answer but we can not break this job further. 7 million is the required limit, this is because we cannot filter the data further functionally. The Transaction size is 10 000 but it does not affect the output.